# Java's GZIPOutputStream refuses to flush

Tags: java, stream, gzipoutputstream

Here is a JUnit test that demonstrates my issue:

```java
package stream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class StreamTest {
    public static class LoopbackStream {
        private final byte[] END_MARKER = new byte[0];
        private final ArrayBlockingQueue<byte[]> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1024);

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
            return new OutputStream() {
                @Override
                public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                    this.write(new byte[] { (byte) b });
                }

                @Override
                public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
                    try {
                        queue.put(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, off, len - off));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                    try {
                        queue.put(END_MARKER);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() {
            return new InputStream() {
                private boolean finished = false;
                private ByteBuffer current = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[0]);

                @Override
                public int read() {
                    if (ensureData()) {
                        return Byte.toUnsignedInt(current.get());
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
                    if (ensureData()) {
                        int position = current.position();
                        current.get(b, off, Math.min(len, current.remaining()));
                        return current.position() - position;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }

                private boolean ensureData() {
                    if (!finished && !current.hasRemaining()) {
                        try {
                            byte[] data = queue.take();
                            current = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                            finished = data == END_MARKER;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return !finished;
                }
            };
        }

    }

    @Test
    void testVanilla() throws IOException {
        LoopbackStream objectUnderTest = new LoopbackStream();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(objectUnderTest.getOutputStream()), true);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objectUnderTest.getInputStream()));

        pw.println("Hello World!");

        assertEquals("Hello World!", br.readLine());
    }

    @Test
    void testVanilla2() throws IOException {
        LoopbackStream objectUnderTest = new LoopbackStream();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(objectUnderTest.getOutputStream()), true);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objectUnderTest.getInputStream()));

        pw.println("Hello World!");
        assertEquals("Hello World!", br.readLine());

        pw.println("Hello Otherworld!");
        assertEquals("Hello Otherworld!", br.readLine());
    }

    @Test
    void testGzipped() throws IOException {
        LoopbackStream objectUnderTest = new LoopbackStream();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(objectUnderTest.getOutputStream(), true)), true);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(objectUnderTest.getInputStream())));

        pw.println("Hello World!");

        assertEquals("Hello World!", br.readLine());
    }
}
```

There are two individual tests. One that uses vanilla input and output streams (which works fine) and another that wraps those streams in their gzip equivalents.

I've used the `GZIPOutputStream`'s `syncFlush` option which I am expecting to automatically flush any remaining bytes from the stream whenever the parent stream is flushed. I'm using the `PrintWriter`'s `autoFlush` option to flush its data whenever it does a `println`.

Is there a better way to force the `GZIPOutputStream` to flush its buffers after a `println`?

Comment: What is the purpose of all this? Are you aware of `mark()` and `reset()`? and `ByteArrayInputStream()`?

Comment: How do `mark()` and `reset()` affect `GZIPOutputStream`?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not the full answer to your question, but it is too long for a comment...

---

**Update:**

After further investigation it seems that it's not the `GZIPOutputStream` that doesn't flush (by adding `System.out.println("xy");` statements in the `public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method you can see that the `GZIPOutputStream` writes two byte arrays into your `OutputStream`: one is the gzip stream header, the other one is the encoded content of the first line of text).

It seems that the reading process blocks because of a bad interaction between the `java.io.InputStreamReader` (respectively the `sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder` it uses) and the `GZIPInputStream`.

Basically, if the `StreamDecoder` needs to read bytes from the underlying stream it tries to read as many bytes as possible (as long as underlying stream reports `in.available() > 0`, implying that the underlying stream can yield some more bytes without blocking)

- [loop in the `StreamDecoder`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#l317)
- [check for `in.available()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#l361)

The problem with this check is that the `InflaterInputStream` (the superclass of the `GZIPInputStream`) always returns `1` for the number of available bytes, even if its source stream has **no** bytes available ([see the source of `InflaterInputStream.available()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.java#l168))

So it seems that while you can write line by line into a `GZIPOutputStream`, you cannot easily read line by line from a `GZIPInputStream`...

---

**Original answer:**

The problem is not the `GZIPOutputStream`, the problem is with the `boolean ensureData()` method that refuses to read more than one block.

The following test fails with vanilla streams too:

```
@Test
void testVanilla2() throws IOException {
    LoopbackStream objectUnderTest = new LoopbackStream();

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(objectUnderTest.getOutputStream()), true);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objectUnderTest.getInputStream()));

    pw.println("Hello World!");
    assertEquals("Hello World!", br.readLine());

    pw.println("Hello Otherworld!");
    assertEquals("Hello Otherworld!", br.readLine());
}
```

---

Comment: You're right, there was a bug in my LoopbackStream class. Thanks! Fixing the bug doesn't fix my actual problem however, so I've updated the code in my original question.

Comment: @spierepf I've updated the answer with my findings from `GZIPOutputStream` / `GZIPInputStream`